# Python Program to split big string into 8 piece sub string and remove all possible duplicate with 1st occurrence

Tags: python

Program output

```
MARTKQTARKSTGGKAPRKQLATKAA
1. MARTKQTA
2.  ARTKQTAR
3.   RTKQTARK
4.    TKQTARKS
```

and so on, remove all duplicates value with 1st occurrence of value

```
import operator
unique_kmer = {}
duplicate_kmer = {}

def printSeq(name, seq):
\\print name
kmers = {}
k = 8
\\window size 8
for i in range(len(seq)-k +1):
    kmer = seq[i:i+k]
\\ break string 1-8 char,then 2-9, 3-10 and so on
    if kmer in unique_kmer:
        continue
        
    if kmer in duplicate_kmer:
        duplicate_kmer[kmer] = ""
        del duplicate_kmer[kmer]
    else:
        unique_kmer[kmer]= name
```

with open(r"fasta file", "r") as f:

```
seq = ""
key = ""
for line in f.readlines():
   
    if line.startswith(">"):
        
        if key and seq:
            
            printSeq(key, seq)
       
        key = line[1:].rstrip()
        seq = ""
    else:
       seq += line.strip()


for k , v in unique_kmer.items():
    print(k + " , " + v)
```

Comment: Hi, what is your *question*?

Comment: hello, after getting a list of all 8size  kmer from fasta file. i just want remove all duplicate 8 size kmer with their 1st occurence

Comment: Do you know what a `set` is?

Comment: No, I dont know what is set.